# How to find duplicate in a matrix/array while ignoring one specific value?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, duplicates

I'm currently writing a sodoku game in java and one rule is that every row must not contain the same number (1-9) more than once. Number 0 indicates that the box is empty.
My "checkRow" boolean-method is supposed to return 'false' if duplicates are found, and 'true' if no duplicates are found (correct row). I know how to find duplicates, but since the value '0' indicates an empty box, duplicates of '0' is allowed.

How do I accomplish this?

This is the code I've come up with so far. It returns 'true' every test case (no duplicates found).

```
public boolean checkRow(int row){
    
       for (int k = 0; k < grid.length; k++){
            for (int i = k + 1; i < grid.length; i++){
                if (grid[row][k] == (grid[row][i]) && grid[row][k] != 0) {
                    return false;                       
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Code using addition array to store found values:

```
public boolean checkRow(int row){
  
  int[] found = new int[9];
  for (int k = 0; k < grid.length; k++){
      if (grid[row][k] > 0 && grid[row][k] < 10){
          found[grid[row][k]]++;
      }
 
      if (found[grid[row][k]] > 1){
          return false;
      }
      
  
     }
    return true;                
}
```

This also returns only true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks correct, what is the problem?

Comment: Instead of using nested loops I'd probably use a temporary array to store the occurences of each number (the number would be the index to the array) and if that number is > 1 for any index other than 0 you've found a duplicate. That way only one loop would be needed.

Comment: @Thomas, I have now come up with code for that solution. But still, it returns true every time. Updated the post with new code, code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: Did you debug your code to see whether  `grid` is the correct array, has the correct length etc.?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Thomas comment, the solution could be as follows (without using global `grid` variable)

```java
public static boolean isRowValid(int[] row) {
    int[] freq = new int[9];

    for (int num : row) {
        if (num > 0 && freq[num - 1]++ > 0) {
            // debugging print
            System.out.printf("Duplicate %d found%n", num);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test

```java
int[][] grid = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    {0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1},
    {3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0},
    {7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 7},
};

for (int[] row : grid) {
    System.out.printf("Row %s has no dups? %s%n", Arrays.toString(row), isRowValid(row));
}
```

Output

```
Row [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] has no dups? true
Row [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] has no dups? true
Row [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0] has no dups? true
Duplicate 1 found
Row [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0] has no dups? false
Duplicate 1 found
Row [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1] has no dups? false
Duplicate 1 found
Row [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9] has no dups? false
Duplicate 1 found
Row [0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1] has no dups? false
Duplicate 3 found
Row [3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0] has no dups? false
Duplicate 3 found
Row [7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 7] has no dups? false
```

---

An equivalent solution using stream API would look like this:

```java
public static boolean isRowValidStream(int[] row) {
    int[] freq = new int[9];
    return Arrays.stream(row) // getIntStream
                 .filter(x -> x > 0) // filter out all zeroes
                 .map(x -> freq[x - 1]++) // calculate frequency
                 .noneMatch(f -> f > 0); // look for the first frequency value 1 
}
```